# jQuery change path to bootstrap icons on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover

I'm making a custom toolbar using bootstrap icons with the file path like the following:

```
images/icons/white/png/font_italic_icon&16.png
```

On `.hover()` how can I replace white to black to make the path like this?

```
images/icons/black/png/font_italic_icon&16.png
```

This will save me a lot of doing something like this for every icon.

```
$(".myclass").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "images/icons/white/png/round_plus_icon&16.png");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "images/icons/black/png/round_plus_icon&16.png");
    }
);
```

Comment: Why can't you put icons in background? It is much easier that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use vanilla JavaScript [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function:

```
      "images/icons/white/png/round_plus_icon".replace("/white/", "/black/");
// -> "images/icons/black/png/round_plus_icon"
```

Putting it together:

```
function () {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    var newsrc = $img.attr("src").replace("/black/", "/white/");
    $img.attr("src", newsrc);
},
function () {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    var newsrc = $img.attr("src").replace("/white/", "/black/");
    $img.attr("src", newsrc);
}
```

Note: It is possible to re-write the above without using `var` by using `jQuery.attr(name, callback)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript, use the css `:hover` event to change the `background-image` of the appropriate icon classes

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use replace http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

    `$(this).find('img').attr( "src",

                               $(this).find('img').attr("src").replace("white","black")

                            );`